# Detect all links that exists pointing to /tmp?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link

I want to find out which file links exist that point to my `/tmp` folder on Ubuntu.

**Background:**
I had a problem, that my `/tmp` folder privileges were changed by some accident to 755.
The system wasn't running correctly any more as a user other than root.

Maybe there is a link to `/tmp` somewhere and the command

```
chmod 755 . -Rf
```

called there in that folder was affecting the main `/tmp` folder.

I had to repair it with:

```
chmod 777 /tmp
chmod +t /tmp
sudo chown root:root /tmp
```

I have only one file system, so there shouldn't be a problem with that.

Comment: Your system might have been rooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
find / -path /proc -prune -o \( -lname '*/tmp' -o -lname '*/tmp/' \) -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Sample output:

```
# find / -path /proc -prune -o -lname '*/tmp' -exec ls -l {} \;
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 sergey sergey 4 Sep 22 11:27 /home/sergey/xxx/tmp -> /tmp
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jun 20 10:28 /usr/tmp -> ../var/tmp
find: `/run/user/sergey/gvfs': Permission denied
```

Comment: that gives lots of errors

Comment: yes, of course. run it as root.

Comment: Yes i did run it as root. `/proc` seems to be the problem

Comment: I modified the command - now it skips the /proc tree

Comment: that's **sometimes!** working, but it finds other tmp symlinks like `/var/www/someapp/html/tmp -> ../tmp
`

Comment: Yes. Intentionally, as you may have some symlink that points to the '/tmp' like this: '../../../tmp'. I believe the list is not very long to check every line printed.

Comment: yes, that list is not long, but it is missing links with / at the end like `test -> /tmp/`. therefore i need `'*/tmp/'` too

Comment: then change the pattern and check again to see your variant))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16990/discussion-between-rubo77-and-serge)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to list all symlinks pointing to an inode. Therefore I would recommend using the standard *find* utility with the *-L* and *-samefile* switches:

- **-samefile** will compare based on the inode of your target file,
- **-L** will include symbolic links in the search, which is what you are looking for.

Here is an example with /bin/dash in /bin:

```
$ find -L  /bin -samefile /bin/dash -exec ls -lhi {} \;
786515 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 29  2012 /bin/sh -> dash
786436 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 108K Mar 29  2012 /bin/dash
```

From this output, you can see both with the inode number (first column) and the arrow (last one) that /bin/sh in a symlink to the /bin/dash. If they were hardlinks, inode number would be the same for different files and there would be no arrow in the last column.

Finally, If I had the need to look for these links on a whole filesystem,  I would exclude some directories such as */dev*, */proc* and */sys* from the search. This would be done with the *-path* and *-prune* swicthes (you can add as many as you want with *-o* switch meaning *or*), *2>/dev/null* is here to mask potential errors:

```
$ sudo find -L  / \( -path /dev -o -path /proc -o -path /sys \) -prune -samefile /bin/dash -exec ls -lhi {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

As searching in a entire filesystem can take a lot of time (mainly depending on its size) I will consider this option as a last resort. It is like searching a needle in a haystack: it is not impossible but takes a lot of effort...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, thanks to this question: [Linux: Find all symlinks of a given 'original' file? (reverse 'readlink')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532241/linux-find-all-symlinks-of-a-given-original-file-reverse-readlink)

```
find / -exec ls -ald {} ';' 2>/dev/null | grep '\-> /tmp' |grep -v /proc/
```

Comment: This will produce the result you are looking for but it will be much slower than solution proposed by me as it will exec `ls` command for each any file it find, while my solution executes `ls` only for sym links that ends up with '/tmp' suffix