# How do I find all the symbolic links to a master file?

Tags: linux, centos, symbolic-link

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out if a symbolic link exists, that points to /tmp?](https://superuser.com/questions/479347/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-symbolic-link-exists-that-points-to-tmp)

I have an mpeg file that has been linked to in a number of directories. I need to replace all those links with links to a new file. How can I find all the links that point to that file? This is on a CentOS 5 machine.

Comment: have you tried `ll`, if it shows something like `->` it means it's a link, I don't remember very well how to do this

Answer (score 0):

The below should do it.  `globstar` should require bash 4.0+

```
shopt -s globstar

# Set the initial filename.  Can be had from $@ if you wanted to.
the_file="filename.mpg"

# Roll through pretty much the entire server
for file in /**; do
    if [[ -l "${file}" ]]; then
        tmp="$(readlink "${file}")"
        [[ "${tmp##*/}" == "${the_file##*/}" ]] && ls -l "${file}"
    fi
done
```